# Out of the box responsive images with Google Polymer?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, polymer, responsive

I just started working with Polymer and their starter kit. I want to have a standard hero image with a text overlay - naturally, I want the image to be responsive. I've gone through all the Iron and Paper elements and can't seem to find anything that works.

I've tried using the Iron image, Flex layout, and Media queries in various compbinations to get what I need, but to no avail. I've found several 3rd party components like [x-imager](https://github.com/addyosmani/x-imager)  that will do the trick, but I would've thought such basic functionality would be available right out of the box like it is with pretty much every "responsive" framework - and yes, while I know Polymer isn't supposed to be a framework, I guess I expected it to be part of their component library. And yes, I also know I can create a simple CSS class that does that like Bootstrap does too, but I'm looking for native functionality, out of the box here.

Is there something I'm missing here or should I just create a custom component and move on?

Comment: What are you trying to do? load different images depending on the viewport size? or just resizing the same image?

Comment: Right now just resizing the same image. I was going to serve different sized images based on viewports later, but getting either solution working is fine with me.

Comment: I think flex-layout should solve that. Can you share a jsfiddle with what you have tried?

Comment: I just used the BS responsive image css to override the iron image class and id: .iron-image-0 #img.iron-image { max-width: 100%; height: auto; display:block; }

Probably not the cleanest way to do it, but it gets the job done. Not sure why the iron image API doesn't support 'max-width' but whatever, it works for now. 

I'll go back and see what I can do with the flexbox layout in a few days and let you know.